# MPU9250 IMU wearable design considerations and device address problem

Tags: i2c, embedded, imu

I need to use 12-16 mpu9250 IMU for wearable design. Each IMU will be placed different places on the body. Therefore, I want to read data from each device by using I2C interface. However, problem is all mpu9250 devices have same device address -0x68- for I2C. So far I come up with multiplexer yet multiplexing might not be a good idea with I2C.

I also learnt that SPI will not be a good solution due to cable lengths.

I am looking for suggestions for overcoming device address problem for I2C interface and also system architecture.
(Another IMU is not an option)

Comment: Rpi4B has a couple of I2C buses.

Comment: Why is multiplexing not a good idea? I think it is an excellent idea.

Comment: Lowering pullup R can reduce noise ingress or better STP cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplexing. There exists chips designed especially for multiplexing I2C, and so far you have no evidence against using them.

Comment: Yeah, its my fault. My professor told me that using mux is against the nature of I2C and he was aware of the fixed device address of mpu. So I thought that solution is too simple for such problem. Anyway I should have go beyond and further investigate the I2C and multiplexing instead of just listening. As you said there exist dedicated chips for that issue. Thanks Everyone.

Comment: Multiplexing is especially used to isolate bus segments, for instance in cases where devices have identical addresses, so that multiple devices with identical addresses can be connected. And also to split the bus into smaller segments with less capacitance, when a single long bus would not work. You need to show your professor I2C application manuals from TI and NXP.